How can I prevent managed_file form field type from reseting options set in the previous field using ajax?
When creating a form that has two selects where the second selects options rely on the first selects value then followed by a managed_file type field submitting the form resets the available options that were set for the second field.
When you submit the form you will receive the error message:
An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.
<?php

namespace Drupal\webform_test\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class WebformTestForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'webform_test_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['select_one'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Select One'),
      '#options' => [
        '1' => $this->t('One'),
        '2' => $this->t('Two'),
        '3' => $this->t('Three'),
      ],
      '#empty_value' => '',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [get_class($this), 'selectAjaxCallback'],
        'disable-refocus' => FALSE, // Or TRUE to prevent re-focusing on the triggering element.
        'wrapper' => 'select-two-wrapper', // This element is updated with this AJAX callback.
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
        ],
      ]
    ];

    $option_1 = [
      'A' => $this->t('A'),
      'B' => $this->t('B'),
      'C' => $this->t('C'),
    ];

    $option_2 = [
      'D' => $this->t('D'),
      'E' => $this->t('E'),
      'F' => $this->t('F'),
    ];

    $option_3 = [
      'G' => $this->t('G'),
      'H' => $this->t('H'),
      'I' => $this->t('I'),
    ];


    switch($form_state->getValue('select_one')) {
      case '1':
        $options = $option_1;
        break;
      case '2':
        $options = $option_2;
        break;
      case '3':
        $options = $option_3;
        break;
      default:
        $options = [];
    }

    $form['select_two'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Select Two'),
      '#options' => $options,
      '#empty_value' => '',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="select-two-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $form['managed_file'] = [
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => $this->t('Managed file'),
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  public static function selectAjaxCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['select_two'];
  }

}

